# Changing Line Color in MSChart Control using Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am working on a Growth Chart using MS Chart Control in VB6. Can someone tell me how can I change color of each line in the diagram. Also I am trying to get the value of the data in the line graph.

Thanks,

AG

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the chart control, and then go to the "Series Color" tab.  Then you can select the series (line of data) you want to change, and set whatever colors you want.

Answer (score 0):

At run time, you can copy a color from one series  MSChart1 to the first (for example) Series other MSChart2:

```
MSChart2.Plot.SeriesCollection(1).DataPoints(-1).Brush.FillColor.Blue = MSChart1.Plot.SeriesCollection(Series).DataPoints(-1).Brush.FillColor.Blue
MSChart2.Plot.SeriesCollection(1).DataPoints(-1).Brush.FillColor.Green = MSChart1.Plot.SeriesCollection(Series).DataPoints(-1).Brush.FillColor.Green
MSChart2.Plot.SeriesCollection(1).DataPoints(-1).Brush.FillColor.Red = MSChart1.Plot.SeriesCollection(Series).DataPoints(-1).Brush.FillColor.Red
```